# Print from database using array but ignore certain columns on data

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code which copies a line of data and pastes it into another sheet as an array, if a cell has been marked which a particular value (x) & then prints.

At the minute it copies the entire line of data, however I need it to ignore certain cells along that line of data.

```
Sub AlterQuote()
Dim FormWks As Worksheet
Dim DataWks As Worksheet
Dim myRng As Range
Dim myCell As Range
Dim iCtr As Long
Dim myAddr As Variant
Dim lOrders As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False


Set FormWks = Sheets("Quote")
Set DataWks = Sheets("Quote Database")

myAddr = Array("G9", "G10", "G11", "G12", "C14", "C15", "C16", "C17", "C18", "C19", "C20", "C21", "B25", "C25", "D25", "E25", "F25", "G25", "H25", "I25", "H38", "I38", "B26", "C26", "D26", "E26", "F26", "G26", "H26", "I26", "H39", "I39", "B27", "C27", "D27", "E27", "F27", "G27", "H27", "I27", "H40", "I40", "B28", "C28", "D28", "E28", "F28", "G28", "H28", "I28", "H41", "I41", "B29", "C29", "D29", "E29", "F29", "G29", "H29", "I29", "H42", "I42", "I30", "H31", "H32", "H33", "H43", "I43", "H44", "H45", "H46", "D57", "D58", "D59", "D60")

With DataWks
  Set myRng = .Range("B3", _
    .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
End With

For Each myCell In myRng.Cells
  With myCell
    If IsEmpty(.Offset(0, -1)) Then
  Else

      .Offset(0, -1).ClearContents
    
      For iCtr = LBound(myAddr) _
        To UBound(myAddr)
        FormWks.Range(myAddr(iCtr)).Value _
          = myCell.Offset(0, iCtr).Value
      Next iCtr

    End If
  End With
Next myCell

MsgBox "quote can now be altered on Quote Sheet"


    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I know it's within this line `With DataWks Set myRng = .Range("B3", _ .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)) End With`   but I can't get it to work

Comment: How do you know that it's `within this line...`? Where is the beginning of the code (the signature (`Sub...`) and whatnot)?

Comment: Sorry the Sub missed off in the original post - just edited to amend this. I don't know for certain, but that part of the code is looking for rows of data marked with an x

Comment: There can be only one row right?  Otherwise you just overwrite the previously-copied row.  In that case you should `Exit For` after making the copy.

Comment: As for the copy process - you have options such as adding a row above the headers on `Quote Database` - for any column which needs to be copied, put the destination cell address for `Quote`: you can then loop over that "mapping" row once you've found the row to be copied.   This has the added advantage of making it clear which column ends up where on the quote sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following on from my comment above: here is one solution which can also be used if you need to transfer data *back* to the database sheet.

Source `Quote Database` sheet with column mappings (Row 2 could be hidden if you think it's distracting):

[image]

Transfer code:

```
Sub AlterQuote()
    
    Const MAPPING_ROW As Long = 2
    Const DATA_ROW1 As Long = 4
    
    Dim FormWks As Worksheet, DataWks As Worksheet, myRng As Range, addr
    Dim rw As Range, rngMap As Range, c As Range, m As Variant, lr As Long
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Set FormWks = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Quote")
    Set DataWks = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Quote Database")
    
    lr = DataWks.Cells(DataWks.rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).row
    If lr < DATA_ROW1 Then lr = DATA_ROW1 'in case no flag set...
    Set myRng = DataWks.Range("A" & DATA_ROW1 & ":A" & lr)
    
    m = Application.match("*", myRng, 0) 'find first value in myRang
    
    If Not IsError(m) Then                'found a flag?
        Set rw = myRng.Cells(m).EntireRow 'the flagged row
        
        With DataWks           'get the range with cell mappings
            Set rngMap = .Range(.Cells(MAPPING_ROW, 1), _
                        .Cells(MAPPING_ROW, .Columns.count).End(xlToLeft))
        End With
        
        For Each c In rngMap.Cells  'loop over the mapping row cells
            addr = c.Value
            If Len(addr) > 0 Then   'does this column get mapped?
                FormWks.Range(addr).Value = rw.Cells(c.Column).Value
            End If
        Next c
        myRng.Cells(m).ClearContents 'clear flag
        MsgBox "quote can now be altered on Quote Sheet"
    Else
        MsgBox "No row is flagged"
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Resulting output on `Quote` worksheet:

[image]

Another approach might be to create a "mapping" worksheet with a table of column headers and destination addresses.

Comment: That code is great at picking the specific columns and copying to the other worksheet. However when it copies to the other worksheet it needs to copy this data into specific cells and not into a single row. Which in the original code is what the array is for.

Comment: Did you try it out?   The cell addresses above the headers are what would be in your current array.

Comment: For example if A9 is flagged then B9>>B4, D9>>C5, E9>>C6 etc.  You can put the values wherever you want.

Comment: Yes - I tested it out & it copied the correct columns from the Quote Database worksheet, however it pasted it as a row of data on Quote worksheet. 
The current array isn't the data that's copied, that's where the values that are copied paste into (if that makes sense). It currently copies the entire row of data and then pastes into the cells within the array.

Comment: It would only do that if the addresses you entered in the mapping row (Row#2 in my screenshot above) all pointed to the same row.  Otherwise, I have no idea how that could happen.  I do understand how your original code works: basically you need to take the values from your array and put each one above the header for the relevant source column, skipping columns which do not need to be transferred.

Comment: I'm sorry I jumped ahead and didn't see the output picture you sent & ended up misunderstanding your code. Got it now - working perfectly. Thank you for you're help.

Comment: Quick question - how do I add the part about clearing the marked row once it's been copied? `For Each myCell In myRng.Cells
  With myCell
    If IsEmpty(.Offset(0, -1)) Then
  Else

      .Offset(0, -1).ClearContents`  this was it in original code

Comment: `myRng.Cells(m).ClearContents` - edited in above

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different solution than Tim Williams' and a bit more like you had it.
It keeps the array in VBA but adds another one keeping track which cells you want to transfer values of otherwise you iterate over the entire row.

```
Sub AlterQuote()
    Const sRow = 3
    Dim FormWks As Worksheet, DataWks As Worksheet
    Dim myRng As Range, iCtr As Long
    Dim myAddr As Variant, arrOffset, m
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Set FormWks = Sheets("Quote")
    Set DataWks = Sheets("Quote Database")
    
    myAddr = Array("G9", "G10", "G11", "G12", "C14", "C15")
    arrOffset = Array(1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8)
    
    With DataWks
        Set myRng = .Range(.Cells(sRow, "A"), _
            .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    End With
    
    m = Application.Match("*", myRng, 0)
    
    If Not IsError(m) And myRng(1, 1).Row > sRow - 1 Then
        For iCtr = LBound(arrOffset) To UBound(arrOffset)
            FormWks.Range(myAddr(iCtr)).Value = myRng(m, 1).Offset(, arrOffset(iCtr)).Value
        Next iCtr
        myRng(m, 1).ClearContents
        MsgBox "Quote can now be altered on Quote sheet"
    Else
        MsgBox "No flag found"
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

This iterates through both arrays at once but you need to make sure it's a 1 to 1 link, i.e. arrOffset(0) (=B8 if the flag is on row 8) is actually the value you want to transfer to myAddr(0) (=G9)

In my opinion it's far clearer in Tim's answer but if you can't incorporate his adjustment to the sheet, this could be an alternate way. Figured this was easier than explaining it in the comments under Tim's answer.

Comment: Also something like `myAddr = Array("A:G9", "B:G10", "D:G11", ...)` then split each element to source column and destination cell.

Comment: Ye, probably should get myself more comfortable working with `Split`, I tend to forget about its ability for ease of use like in this case.